# how to close the bootstrap navbar on small devices when clicked on a menu item?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is the code i am using for doing the task. It works fine when i resize the window on pc but not working on mobile.

```
$('.nav li a').on('click',function(){
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, and you want to collapse the menu whenever a user clicks something inside it..

**Just use:**

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: Oops, this answer wasn't for this question! Anyways could you replicate the issue on a Fiddle or something like that, so we can see whats wrong?